# Ordering results of eager-loaded nested models in Node Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a complex set of associated models. The models are associated using join tables, each with an attribute called 'order'. I need to be able to query the parent model 'Page' and include the associated models, and sort those associations by the field 'order'.

The following is having no effect on the results' sort order:

```
db.Page.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.Gallery,
    order: ['order', 'DESC'],
    include: [{
      model: db.Artwork,
      order: ['order', 'DESC']
    }]
  }],
})
```

Comment: Annoying naming of your example fields. Firstly, both the models are being ordered on a field with the same name. That name is the same as the operation.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I believe you can do:

```
db.Page.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.Gallery
    include: [{
      model: db.Artwork
    }]
  }],
  order: [
    // sort by the 'order' column in Gallery model, in descending order.

    [ db.Gallery, 'order', 'DESC' ], 


    // then sort by the 'order' column in the nested Artwork model in a descending order.
    // you need to specify the nested model's parent first.
    // in this case, the parent model is Gallery, and the nested model is Artwork

    [ db.Gallery, db.ArtWork, 'order', 'DESC' ]
  ]
})
```

There are also a bunch of different ways, or things you can do when ordering. Read more here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#ordering-and-grouping

Comment: And to think I've been screwing this up for the last year.

Comment: order: [                                                                                      [db.Sequelize.col('order'), 'DESC'], // for page table
    [ db.Gallery, 'order', 'DESC' ],
    [ db.Gallery, db.ArtWork, 'order', 'DESC' ]
  ]

Comment: I want to kiss you

Comment: what if I want to order the artwork results within the page? adding 'order' in the include of the `Artwork` does not seem to have any effect on the order of the included results

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65268641/3411787) helped me, I had to add `order` in main table, instead of my include block. I already had 1 order added, adding another order in same array worked well. My final include in main table: `order: [["id", "desc"], [IncludedModel, "id", "asc"],],`

Answer (score 36):

If you also use 'as' and let's say you want to order by 'createdDate' , the query looks like this:

```
DbCategoryModel.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: DBSubcategory,
            as: 'subcategory',
            include: [
                {
                    model: DBProduct,
                    as: 'product',
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
    order: [
        [
            {model: DBSubcategory, as: 'subcategory'},
            {model: DBProduct, as: 'product'},
            'createdDate',
            'DESC'
        ]
    ]
})
```

Comment: Should this work with foreign keys aswell? I'm getting Unhandled rejection TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at Object.QueryGenerator.quote (/Users/kristoffer/web/fitch/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:869:76)

Comment: Yes, it works, in the example "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145702/create-a-composite-index-with-associated-data/38201524#38201524", using my models declaration, just use the following code: 
User.findAll({
  raw: 'true',
  include: [
    {
      model: UserAttribute,
      as: "UserAttribute"
    }
  ],
  order: [
    [
      {
        model: UserAttribute,
        as: 'UserAttribute'
      },
      'userId',
      'DESC'
    ]
  ]
})
  .then((users) => {
    console.log('users', users)
    process.exit()
  })

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks so much for this answer. It's 7 years already and still actively helping

Answer (score 5):

```
order: [
[ db.Sequelize.col('order'), 'DESC'],    /*If you want to order by page module as well you can add this line*/
[ db.Gallery, db.ArtWork, 'order', 'DESC' ]
]
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: It orders only eager loading, not the querying module.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
let getdata = await categories_recipes.findAll({   
                    order:[ 
                        [{model: recipes, as: 'recipesdetails'},'id', 'DESC'] // change your column name like (id and created_at)
                    ],
                    include:[{
                        model:recipes, as : "recipesdetails",
                        include:[{
                            model:recipe_images, as: "recipesimages",
                        }],
                        where:{
                            user_id:data.id
                        },
                        required: true,
                    }]
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, another thing that also works is using `sequelize.col` as in:

```
db.Page.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.Gallery
    include: [{
      model: db.Artwork
    }]
  }],
  order: [
    [ sequelize.col('Gallery.order', 'DESC' ], 
    [ sequelize.col('Gallery.Artwork.order', 'DESC' ]
  ]
})
```

In this particular case it is slightly worse than the Arrays from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30017078/895245 (which more explicitly use existing Js classes rather than magic strings) but it seems that in most cases besides `order:`, `.col` is accepted but arrays aren't so it is good to have it in mind too.

There are some additional difficulties to overcome when you also need to `limit:` in nested includes:

- [how can i use limit in include model using sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186006/how-can-i-use-limit-in-include-model-using-sequelize)
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8802

When limiting on toplevel only, it seems that `subQuery: false` is required e.g. as in:

```
  u0WithComments = await User.findOne({
    where: { id: u0.id },
    order: [[
      'Comments', 'body', 'DESC'
    ]],
    limit: 1,
    subQuery: false,
    include: [{
      model: Comment,
    }],
  })
```

Comment: Is there a missing closing bracket in `sequelize.col('Gallery.Artwork.order', 'DESC'`?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to populate the order property of the root model (in this case, db.Page).

Instead, I added order to the nested model. In this example, db.Artwork.

BUT, the Sequelize's order property cannot be an array of strings, where every string is a column name and the last string is the direction. Eg:

```
// Failed:
order: ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'DESC'],
```

Instead, it must be composed of an array where each element is another array composed of two elements:

- the column we wish to order, and
- the direction

Eg:

```
// Worked:
order: [['column1', 'ASC'], ['column2', 'DESC'], ['colum3', 'DESC']],
```

So the approach that worked for me was to sort the contents of db.Artwork by the column `order` in descendant direction, was:

```
include: [{
  model: db.Artwork,
  order: [['order', 'DESC']]
}]
```

I got that answer from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003020/2730233) I found here on SO.