# Sequelize: Eager Loading and Ordering (on parent table)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm Sequelize in a [FeathersJS](http://feathersjs.com/) project and I'm having an issue when attempting to eager load associations and ordering by parent table. If I just add the order **OR** the include to the query everything works fine, it's when I use both that I get the error: `Unhandled rejection Error: 'sales_flat_order' in order / group clause is not valid association`

Query:

```
sequelize.models.orders
    .findAll({
      limit: 10,
      include: [ sequelize.models.items ],
      order: [[ sequelize.models.orders, 'createdAt' ]],
    })
    .then(orders => {
      // Error
    });
```

Order Model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(sequelize) {
  const order = sequelize.define('orders', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, field: 'entity_id' },
    customerEmail: { type: Sequelize.STRING, field: 'customer_email' },
    customerFirstName: { type: Sequelize.STRING, field: 'customer_firstname' },
    customerLastName: { type: Sequelize.STRING, field: 'customer_lastname' },
    state: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    grandTotal: { type: Sequelize.FLOAT, field: 'grand_total' },
    createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, field: 'created_at' },
    updatedAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, field: 'updated_at' },
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'sales_flat_order',
    classMethods: {
      associate(models) {
        order.hasMany(models.items, { foreignKey: 'orderId' });
      }
    }
  });

  return order;
};
```

Item Model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(sequelize) {
  const item = sequelize.define('items', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, field: 'item_id' },
    orderId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, field: 'order_id' },
    productId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, field: 'product_id' },
    productType: { type: Sequelize.STRING, field: 'product_type' },
    sku: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    qtyOrdered: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, field: 'qty_ordered' },
    price: { type: Sequelize.FLOAT },
    createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, field: 'created_at' },
    updatedAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, field: 'updated_at' },
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'sales_flat_order_item',
    classMethods: {
      associate(models) {
        item.belongsTo(models.orders, { foreignKey: 'orderId' });
      }
    }
  });

  return item;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordering results of eager-loaded models in Node Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995116/ordering-results-of-eager-loaded-models-in-node-sequelize)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that

```
order: [[ sequelize.models.orders, 'createdAt' ]]
```

tries to order by the column 'createdAt' of the *associated* model sequelize.models.orders. Since you wrote

```
sequelize.models.orders
.findAll({
```

and try to order by the *associated* model `sequelize.models.orders`, you try to reference the model itself as an association. This does not work because you created associations between orders and items but not between orders and orders.

The code you're looking for is probably simply

```
order: [['createdAt', 'ASC' ]]
```

which orders by the model on which you applied `findAll()`. So it orders by `orders.createdAt`.