# sequelize - order by column from included model

Tags: sequelize.js, sql-order-by

I can't figure out how to order by a column that is in my included model.  But I'm not even returning that field in the attributes.  I just want to order by it if that is possible.  Or I can return it and not use as long as I can sort by it.

```
const users = await db.User.findAll({
    raw: true,
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'Permission.type'
    ],
    include: [
    {
        model: db.Permission,
        where: { id: { [Op.lte]: 2 } },
        attributes: [],
        order: [[{ model: db.Permission }, 'id', 'DESC']]
    }
    ]
});
```

In the `include` block the `order` block does nothing right now.  But I have an attribute in my Permission model called `id` that I want to order all results by.  I am fine with adding `Permission.id` to my `attributes` if that is necessary.  But I tried it and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just move `order` option from `include` to main options:

```
const users = await db.User.findAll({
    raw: true,
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'Permission.type'
    ],
    include: [
    {
        model: db.Permission,
        where: { id: { [Op.lte]: 2 } },
        attributes: []
    }
    ],
    order: [[{ model: db.Permission }, 'id', 'DESC']]
});
```

Also maybe you should indicate `id` in `include` attributes.

Comment: OK, that worked!  I couldn't get it to work before but I was changing several things at the same time.  I had to return the id in the main attributes as well.  If I tried returning it in the include attributes it broke and I got no results back.

Comment: Please never try to change several things at once. That way you cannot say what exactly caused an issue.