# Why the sequelize include order does not work?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have read several issues mentioning ordering include models in sequelize but haven't found any that would solve my problem. The case seems to be simple so I am missing something but don't know what...

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Definition:**

```
models.Account.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'AccountUser'});
models.User.belongsToMany(models.Account, {through: 'AccountUser'});

models.Account.hasMany(models.AccountUser)
models.AccountUser.belongsTo(models.Account)

models.User.hasMany(models.AccountUser)
models.AccountUser.belongsTo(models.User)
```

**Query:**

```
const user = await models.User.findOne({
        where: {
            code: userCode,
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: models.AccountUser,
                order: [ ['lastLoginAt', 'desc'] ],
                include: {
                    model: models.Account,
                }
            }
        ]
})
```

**Result**

The AccountUser array is NOT sorted DESC but ASC.

**Versions**

Sequelize: 6.5.1
PostgreSQL: 13.1

Answer (score 0):

I totally missed position of the order (in the root instead of include). My mistake.

[Ordering results of eager-loaded models in Node Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995116/ordering-results-of-eager-loaded-models-in-node-sequelize)