# Sequelize ordering for asssociated model does not work

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to order tasks by 'position'

Task is associated model to the Column
Column is associated model to the Project

Code below does not work, but it seems correct
I have tryed to fix it based on Sequelize docs and description of this issue [enter link description here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4553)

```
const project = await Project.findByPk(request.params.id,
                { include: [
                    { model: User },
                    { model: Column, as: 'columns',
                        include: [{ 
                            model: Task, as: 'tasks',
                            order: [
                                [{model: Task, as: 'tasks'}, 'position', 'DESC']
                            ]
                        }]
                    }
                ] }
            )
            response.send(project)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995116/ordering-results-of-eager-loaded-models-in-node-sequelize)

```
const project = await Project.findByPk(request.params.id,
                { include: [
                    { model: User },
                    { model: Column, as: 'columns',
                        include: [{ 
                            model: Task, as: 'tasks'
                        }]
                    }
                ],
                order: [
                    [{ model: Column, as: 'columns'}, {model: Task, as: 'tasks'}, 'position', 'DESC']
                ] }
            )
```