# Sequelize: DatabaseError - Unknown column in 'order clause'

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

### TLDR:

The inclusion of the order direction 'ASC' or 'DESC' property causes the error `Unknown column 'application.ASC' in 'order clause'`

```
const applications = await Application.findAll({
    order: ['createdAt', 'ASC'],
    distinct: true,
    attributes: [ 
        'id',
        'applicantId',
        'jobId',
    ]
});
```

### Original:

I've been getting this error and I can't quite work out why. I assumed it was a naming problem with the 'createdAt' field, but it seems to be the 'ASC'/'DESC' property that the error is pointing to that's causing the problem

This works:

```
const applications = await Application.findAll({
    order: ['createdAt'],      
    distinct: true,
    attributes: [ 
        'id',
        'applicantId',
        'jobId',
    ]
});
```

SQL query being run:

```
SELECT `id`, `applicantId`, `jobId` FROM `applications` AS `application` ORDER BY `application`.`createdAt`;
```

But this doesn't: (adding 'ASC'/'DESC' to the order property: `order: ['createdAt', 'ASC'],`)

```
const applications = await Application.findAll({
    order: ['createdAt', 'ASC'],      
    distinct: true,
    attributes: [ 
        'id',
        'applicantId',
        'jobId',
    ]
});
```

SQL:

```
SELECT `id`, `applicantId`, `jobId` FROM `applications` AS `application` ORDER BY `application`.`createdAt`, `application`.`ASC`;
```

Resulting in: `Unknown column 'application.ASC' in 'order clause'`

I don't know why it seems to be treating 'ASC' as a column? I think I'm following the correct syntax, described [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#ordering-and-grouping)

This is my model:

```
const Application = sequelize.define('application', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        notNull: true
    }
});
```

I thought explicitly adding the createdAt property to the model might make a difference to the query being run, or the error, but it doesn't:

```
const Application = sequelize.define('application', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        notNull: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        field: 'created_at',
    }
});
```

This is the table in WorkBench:

[image: Application table]

Would appreciate input as I've got myself a little mixed up.

Thanks

Comment: `The order option takes an array of items to order the query by or a sequelize method. These items are themselves arrays in the form [column, direction]. ` https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#ordering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to indicate a direction of sorting then you need to use extended syntax of `order` option - an array of arrays with pairs - a column name and a sorting direction:

```js
order: [['createdAt', 'ASC']],
```

Comment: you continue to be a legend. Thank you very much!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Apparently, the order property must be an array in which each element is an array composed of two elements: the column and the direction. 
I had a deeply include table and this answer worked like a charm. Thank you for it.