# sort with where not working in include model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

previously i wanted to add sort order in included model and i got answer from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995116/ordering-results-of-eager-loaded-nested-models-in-node-sequelize)

```
db.Page.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.Gallery,
    as:"hasGallery",
    where:{}, // not working but without where it is working
  }],
  order: [
    [ 'hasGallery', 'order', 'DESC' ], 
  ]
})
```

suppose where is null for db.Gallery then i am getting correct answer but when there is condition in where for db.Gallery, then i am getting error
**SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "hasGallery"**

i tried other solution not working

Comment: Please show the query with a real condition in `where` and also association definitions